# Sending data as `SNMP Inform`

Tags: java, networking, snmp, net-snmp

I need to gather some data from the web page (web page scraping), parse it, save it to a text file and then send that data out as `SNMP Inform`.

What is `SNMP Inform`? Is there a way to send it out from my application programmatically?

Please keep in mind that the data collection application is written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

1. A quick recap on the difference between TRAPs and INFORMs: A TRAP is
   a SNMP message sent from one application to another via UDP. Usually SNMP Agent sends out SNMP traps and SNMP Manager (Trap Receiver) receives them. It is
   used to notify the other application that something has happened
   like some sort of alarm condition. The problem with TRAPs is that they're
   unacknowledged so you don't actually know if the remote application
   received it. SNMPv2 PDUs fixed this by introducing the notion of an
   INFORM, which is nothing more than an acknowledged TRAP.
2. You can use **SNMP4J** library for Java to send out SNMP traps/informs.